# Using data from API with Chart JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, chart.js

I am getting data from an api and then reformatting part of it into an array using .map(), I am successfully able to do this, but when it comes time to pass it into Chart JS as data it does work. I am able to pass in a normal, hard coded, array but not my own data...

I tried using an Angular directive (NG2-Charts) to help out thinking maybe that was the problem, but that doesn't work either...

Component.ts:
    ... Other variable and stuff up here...

```
getStockData() {
    this.stocksService.getStockData()
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            this.stockOpen.push(response[i]['open']);
          }
          console.log('after loop: ', this.stockOpen);
        },
        (error) => console.error(error)
      );
      console.log('real: ', this.stockOpen);
      console.log('test: ', this.testData);
  }

  // Chart JS version
  buildStockChart() {
    var ctx = document.querySelector("#chart");
    this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [1,2,3,4,5],
        datasets: [
          { 
            data: this.stockOpen,
            borderColor: "#3cba9f",
            fill: false
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true
          }],
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // NG2-Charts version
  public lineChartData:Array<any> = [
    {data: this.testData},
  ];
  public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
  public lineChartOptions:any = {
    responsive: true
  };
```

Result from console.log():
[image]

Comment: Have you tried logging after the for loop (inside of the subscribe closure)?

Comment: @Hodrobond I just tried it and updated the post. It is different but I'm still not totally sure what the issue is

Comment: In the first set of `console.log`s, the 'real' was empty because it wasn't populated yet. Now it looks like you have populated data, and I'm not sure what else is wrong. My guess would be you're trying to use `stockOpen` before it gets set. When do you call `buildStockChart` in relation to `getStockData`, and can you ensure it waits to build until you've gotten your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When are you calling the `buildStockChart()` method?

You should call it right after the for loop into the callback you pass to the subscribe method, since that's the moment when `this.stockOpen` is populated (before that moment it will be empty as you are seeing in the console).

Comment: Yeah this worked. Still getting used to lifecycle hooks, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

i also have same problem with chart JS on angular so i force to use another chart.
im now using angular 2 chart js.

i think the problem here is the delay of data  fetch by API, the CHART component is already render on html view but the data is still not fetch by the API service.

try to add  this code on your code block. This will handle the data if API service data is available.
()=>{this.buildStockChart();}

---

```
 this.stocksService.getStockData()
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            this.stockOpen.push(response[i]['open']);
          }
          console.log('after loop: ', this.stockOpen);
        },
        ()=>{
        this.buildStockChart();
        }
      );
      console.log('real: ', this.stockOpen);
      console.log('test: ', this.testData);
  }
```

This chart is easy to manage for dynamic instances.

Hope this chart will work on you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-chartjs

Comment: @Joseph Agbing WOw amazing!

Answer (score 0):

As @Joseph Agbing, I was unable to get it work with angular 7. I'm now using `chart.js` only

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

### with into my `someChart.component.html`

`<div style="display: block"><!--Mandatory div including chart-->
    <canvas id="canvas">{{chart}}</canvas>
  </div>`

### into my `someChart.component.ts`

called from my `httpClient.post(...).subscribe(lData => (setChartDataFromEntities(lDataProcessed), ...)`

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

export class someClass {

/**
* 
* @param aDate 
* @param aChargeUnitArray 
*/
setChartDataFromEntities( aDate: Date, aChargeUnitArray: ChargeUnit[] ){
    console.debug('setChartDataFromEntities->', aChargeUnitArray)
    let lChartDataArray = []
    let lChartDataLineDataArray: Array<Number> = []
    let lChartLabelsArray: string[] = []
    let l_s: string
    aChargeUnitArray.forEach(element => {
        lChartDataLineDataArray.push(element.charge)
        lChartLabelsArray.push(MiscHelper.dateTimeHMSForChart(element.timestamp))
    });
    lChartDataArray.push(
        {
            data: lChartDataLineDataArray,
            label: MiscHelper.dateForGui(aDate),
        }
    )

    this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: lChartLabelsArray,
        datasets: lChartDataArray
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            display: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            display: true
        }],
        }
    }
    });    

    this.statusMessage = 'Chart loaded'
}
```

hope it helps somebody more than the day I wasted trying to get it work...